# Using ednote/manyfoot: Is there a way to toggle paragraph footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, manyfoot

Is there any way to toggle a given footnote class between paragraph footnotes and regular footnotes using ednotes/manyfoot? (I know this is possible with other footnote packages, but for various reasons I am compelled to use ednotes.)

What I want is a footnote class, sat footnoteC, which will usually appear in paragraph format for short footnotes, but which I can sometimes toggle to non-paragraph style for the occasional longer note. I don't want to use a different footnote class, say footnoteB, for these longer notes, because I don't want them to have a different counter and to show up in a different line of the footer.

A MWE, for what it's worth:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{ednotes}

\newfootnote[para]{C}
\newcounter{footnoteC} \newcommand{\footnoteC}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteC}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteC \FootnotetextC\thefootnoteC}

\begin{document}

Some text\footnoteC{A note.} that has paragraph footnotes.\footnoteC{Another note.}  
But occasionally I want to have a long note that starts its own line.\footnoteC{A 
long note that is supposed to be on its own line below the first two.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing quite the same issue. I am using the `manyfoot` package in **para** style, but need one of the notes in a separate line. Until now I am using the command `\newline` at the end of the previous note and at the end of the note I want to separate. This can cause an overlap with the page numbers on the footer at some pages, but might serve for you.

Comment: If you showed an example of code doing this, it would make your answer more useful.